# How to render Django query set as column wise into html table?

Tags: python, django, html-table, django-templates, django-views

Let's say my sql table looks like this..

**products table**

```
--------------------------------
| id | Model| Manufacturer     |
--------------------------------
| 1  | ABC  | Samsung          |
| 2  | XYZ  | LG               | 
| 3  | ZYX  | Sony             |
--------------------------------
```

in django view i fetched all records from this table and passed it to template..

```
def compare(request):
    product_ids = request.GET.get('product_ids')
    products = Product.objects.filter(id__in=product_ids)
    return render(request, 'compare.html', {'products': products})
```

as query_set result records comes like one after the other we can say it is following row wise but for this case in template i wanted to create an  html table and the result should come like this ..

```
--------------------------------------------
|id           | 1       | 2        | 3     |
|Model        | ABC     | XYZ      | ZYX   |
|Manufacturer | Samsung | LG       | Sony  |
--------------------------------------------
```

By looking at above example you can see data is rendered as column wise.

so please suggest me a better method in Django by which i can achieve this and also please correct me if i'm wrong as i'm beginner in Django.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use *values_list()* and convert your queryset to list

```
products = list(Product.objects.filter(id__in=product_ids).values_list('id', 'Model', 'Manufacturer'))
# OUTPUT: [(1, 'ABC', 'Samsung'), (2, 'XYZ', 'LG'), (3, 'ZYX', 'Sony')]
```

Now transpose this 2d matrix using *zip*

```
t_products = list(zip(*products))
# OUTPUT: [(1, 2, 3), ('ABC', 'XYZ', 'ZYX'), ('Samsung', 'LG', 'Sony')]
```

finally you can loop over it in your template

```
<table>
  <tbody>
    {% for pl in t_products %}
    <tr>
      {% for l in pl%}
         <td>{{l}}</td>
      {% endfor %} 
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `pandas.DataFrame.transpose()` i.e.,

```
import pandas as pd
from django_pandas.io import read_frame
df = read_frame(product)
table_html = df.transpose().to_html()
```

You just pass the `table_html` string to the template; no template logic needed here.  There are several ways to convert a QuerySet to a DataFrame.  Here I'm using the [django-pandas package](https://github.com/chrisdev/django-pandas).

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with this;

```
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>ID</th>
      {% for product in products %}<td>{{ product.id }}</td>{% endfor %}
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Model</th>
      {% for product in products %}<td>{{ product.model }}</td>{% endfor %}
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Manufacturer</th>
      {% for product in products %}<td>{{ product.manufacturer }}</td>{% endfor %}
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks but i'm looking for a solution which comes to result without doing multiple iteration like this.

Comment: another way, you can do it with templatetags.. but, basicly it still same..

Comment: because if it is just for 3 fields in a records it's ok to do this way but if it is like 10 fields or more it's a bad practice to do this way right ??

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Bootstrap's grid system](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/css/#grid):

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-3">
        <p>id</p>
        <p>Model</p>
        <p>Manufacturer</p>
    </div>
    {% for product in products %}
    <div class="col-xs-3">
        <p>{{ product.id }}</p>
        <p>{{ product.model }}</p>
        <p>{{ product.manufacturer }}</p>
    </div>
    {% endfor %}
</div>
```

`col-xs-3` means the style will apply from extra-small screen sizes and upwards (i.e. all screens) and `3` means it will split the screen into 12/3 = 4 parts. If you wanted, for example, 6 columns then you'd have to use `col-xs-2`.

If you don't want to bring in the overhead of Bootstrap then you could use [flex boxes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Using_CSS_flexible_boxes) which were brought in for CSS3.

```
.flexcontainer {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
}
```

Comment: This is a compare page and there will be n number of product so i cannot go with bootstrap grid system and yes `display:flex` might work but i'm looking for a solution with python way :),  Thanks